# Kivy graphics with ethernet data reception

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, kivy

My kivy code has to move a widget smoothly linearly from point A to point B and also receive UDP packet via ethernet cable. For now the widget moves smoothly from A to C (C between line AB)and then stops to receive data (may be 0.5 to 1 second) and then the widget moves again.
The movement is not smooth due to this. Any idea how to solve this issue?
I am using socket module from python for data reception.

I even tried thread programming. It did not help, same issue.

```
class DemoCreator(AnchorLayout):

    ev_status = NumericProperty(None)  # get ev status(UDP packet)

    def receive_ev_status(self):
        r = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        r.bind(('', 5555))
        prev_data = 0
        data, _ = r.recvfrom(1024)

        if not data:
            data = prev_data
        return int.from_bytes(data, 'little')

    def update_ev_status(self, dt):
        self.ev_status = self.receive_ev_status()


class DemoApp(App):

    def build(self):

        hmi = DemoCreator()
        hmi.map_box.host_car.start((450, 0)

        Clock.schedule_interval(hmi.update_ev_status, 0.5)
        Clock.schedule_interval(hmi.map_box.update_car, 1 / 60)

        return hmi

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

how to receive data using ports for a kivy application without disturbing its graphics ?

Comment: Using threads for this is an appropriate solution. Whatever you tried before was probably wrong somehow.

Comment: @inclement  Can you take a look at my code?

Comment: @inclement Can you direct me to any resources about threading in kivy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of `Clock.schedule_interval()` for your ethernet reception. The `Clock.schedule` family schedules methods to be run on the main thread, so your ethernet work is being done on the same (GUI) thread as your widget motion. That affects the GUI performance. Put your ethernet code in another thread by using something like `threading.Thread(target=self.ethernet_recv).start()`. The target method will need to do your looping to call your `self.receive_ev_status()` at 0.5 second intervals.

Have a look at [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#thread-objects)